# getting embedded flowplayer to play a local video file

Tags: html, video, flowplayer, object-tag

I embedded `flowplayer` on an `html page` using the following `<object` tag .It successfully plays the mentioned video from their site (ie from url `http://stream.flowplayer.org/KimAronson-TwentySeconds1318.flv`

However,I would like to play a video from my local filesystem. say `/home/me/videos/test.flv`

How do I mention the url in this case? What `baseurl ,url` values should I provide?

```
<object width="320" height="200" id="undefined" name="undefined"
  data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.10.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
  <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.10.swf" />
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
  <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"baseUrl":"http://stream.flowplayer.org","url":"http://stream.flowplayer.org/KimAronson-TwentySeconds1318.flv"},"canvas":{"backgroundColor":"#112233"},"plugins":{"controls":{"time":false,"volume":true,"fullscreen":false},"content":{"url":"flowplayer.content-3.2.8.swf"}}}' />
  </object>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly ask the flowplayer to load a file from your local file system. Think about all this flash (swf) files trying to load this file from a remote server, they just cannot simply use whatever in your file system as a resource.

The easiest way to test it out is set up a local server. Be it Apache, IIS, or whatever server you like or easy for you. And then change the config's url to the video's url on your local server, which will solve your problem.

You don't need to change any thing for baseUrl as this is where all this flowplayer flash files being loaded. For example, the content url in your provided code will be baseurl + content.url => http://stream.flowplayer.org/flowplayer.content-3.2.8.swf.

However, once you put your page into production, you may need to consider about hosting this flash files locally to avoid fetch the remote flowplayer server every time. In that case, you need to change the baseUrl to whatever the new server should be.